# TemplateSyntaxError - Invalid filter: 'translate'

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates, angular-translate

In my `angularJs` application, with `django` backend, I'm using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) to handle multilingual work. It is working fine for `AngularJs` (html and controller) files, but for `login file, that is rendering as template from django`, it is giving exception

> TemplateSyntaxError at /login
>
> Invalid filter: 'translate'

Here is exception detail;

[image: First Exception]

This is html where I'm trying to use `translate`

[image: Login Form HTML]

`Username` key is defined in related language `json file`, that is referenced in configuration file of loginApp like this;

```
angular.module('loginApp')
.factory("asyncLoader", asyncLoader)
.config(config);

config.$inject = ['$translateProvider'];
function config($translateProvider)
{
 $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
 $translateProvider.useLoader('asyncLoader');
}

asyncLoader.$inject = ['$q', '$timeout', '$http'];
function asyncLoader($q, $timeout, $http)
{
return function(options){
    
    var defferred = $q.defer(), translations;
    var resturl = "static/loginApp/lang" + options.key + ".json";
    
    $http.get(resturl, {cache:false}).success(function(translations) {
        defferred.resolve(translations);
        
    }).error(function(translations){
        defferred.reject(translations);
        
    });
    
    $timeout(function (){
        defferred.resolve(translations);
    },2000);
    
    return defferred.promise;
};
}
```

This whole setting is working file with login controller file, but when I use it in html, it throws `template rendering` error.

this is how I'm rendering `login.html' as template in my django app` views.py`

```
def LoginTemplate(request):
return HttpResponse(get_template('login.html').render())
```

I don't know what I'm missing, Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you import the correct module in your template file ?

Comment: @Antwane Yes, I'm importing correct module, it works fine if I remove 'translate' from html